# Python Float division ny zero Error

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Python Float division by zero error. I can't find any error in this. Can anybody fix it ? I'm using this code in the Odoo version 10. I tried some other ways but it was not working. Hope it might be helpful to somebody also.

```
class etq_results(models.Model):

    _name = "etq.result"
    _description = "Exam Result"

    exam_id = fields.Many2one('etq.exam', string="Exam", readonly=True)
    user_id = fields.Many2one('student.student',"Exam candidate / Student", translate=True)
    score = fields.Float(string="Score", compute="_compute_score", store=True)
    results = fields.One2many('etq.result.question', 'result_id', string="Results", readonly=True)
    token = fields.Char(string="Token")
    state = fields.Selection([('incomplete','Incomplete'), ('complete','Complete')], string="State")

    @api.one
    @api.depends('results')
    def _compute_score(self):
        num_questions = self.env['etq.result.question'].search_count([('result_id', '=', self.id)])
        correct_questions = self.env['etq.result.question'].search_count([('result_id', '=', self.id), ('correct', '=', True)])
        # raise UserError(_(float(num_questions)))
        if float(num_questions) and float(correct_questions) is None:
            self.score = 0.0
        else:
            self.score = float(correct_questions) + "/" + float(num_questions) + " " + (float(correct_questions) / float(num_questions)) * 100.0 + "%"
```

Comment: Can you show your error trace? Also what are you trying to do with your `else` clause? You have a mixture of `float` and `str` in your `self.score` statement. Are you trying to store it as a string?

Comment: `500: Internal Server Error`
Error
Error message:

`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`
Traceback

Comment: `if float(num_questions) or float(correct_questions) == 0.0:`

I have tried this too Mr.@abarnert

Comment: @MuhammadFaizalNS Yes, that's also wrong, for a different reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do with your `if` test is this:

```
if not float(num_questions):
```

In other words, if `float(num_questions)` is zero—and therefore falsey—you want to skip the code with the `/ float(num_questions)` in it, which would be illegal. It doesn't matter what `correct_questions` is here. After all, dividing `0 / 3` isn't a division by zero; it's fine.

What you actually wrote is a completely different test:

```
if float(num_questions) and float(correct_questions) is None:
```

You're testing that `float(num_questions)` is truthy—the exact opposite of what you want—and also that `float(correct_questions) is None`—which can never be true, because only `None is None`. So, you'll always hit the `else`. And therefore, you'll get a division by zero if the `num_questions` value is zero.

And your attempted fix doesn't make much difference:

```
if float(num_questions) or float(correct_questions) == 0.0:
```

You're testing that `num_questions` is truthy, which is still the opposite of what you want, or that `correct_questions` is 0. The only way the first part can be false is if there are no questions—in which case there are no correct questions, so the second part will be true. So now, you always hit the `if` and always show `0.0`.

---

If you get past that, you have another problem:

```
self.score = float(correct_questions) + "/" + float(num_questions) + " " + (float(correct_questions) / float(num_questions)) * 100.0 + "%"
```

You're trying to add floats and strings. That's illegal. What you probably want here is string formatting, something like this:

```
pct = float(correct_questions) / float(num_questions) * 100.0
self.score = f"{correct_questions}/{num_questions} {pct}%"
```

Or, if you're on an older version of Python:

```
self.score = "{}/{} {}%".format(correct_questions, num_questions, pct)
```

And you probably want your `if` clause to match the same format instead of just showing `0.0`?

```
self.score = "0.0/0.0 0.0%"
```

---

While we're at it, calling `float(correct_questions)` over and over again makes your code harder to read (and a bit slower, but that probably doesn't matter). Why not just call it once and store the result?

Also, are these really floats rather than ints? Something called `num_questions` that comes from a database count operation is surely going to be a whole number, right?

So, putting it all together:

```
num_questions = int(self.env['etq.result.question'].search_count([('result_id', '=', self.id)]))
correct_questions = int(self.env['etq.result.question'].search_count([('result_id', '=', self.id), ('correct', '=', True)]))

pct = 0.0
if num_questions:
    pct = correct_questions * 100.0 / num_questions
self.score = f"{correct_questions}/{num_questions} {pct}%"
```